# Loading view configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I would like to do something like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('products/list', {
    controller: 'ProductListCtrl',
    templateUrl : 'products/list/view.html',
    resolve : { data : function(){
        ...
    },
    loadingTemplateUrl : 'general/loader.html'
}
});
```

I would like to have the loading page in a different view.

This would make the code in the view and controller of every page cleaner, (no <...ng-include ng-show="loading"...>). This would also mean that I don't have to $scope.$watch the data for changes. Is there a clean solution to do something similar (not necessarily in the .config method) or an alternative library to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show some general template for all state transitions while the data is resolved, my suggestion is to listen to the events fired by the routing library. This allows to use one central point to handle all state transitions instead of polluting the routing config (which I think will not be that easy to do).

Please see the docs for `$routeChangeStart`, `$routeChangeSuccess` and of course `$routeChangeError` at [the angular router docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeStart)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone could be interested in what I did: I created a new service and a new view directive. It could seem like a lot of work, but doing this was much easier than I had expected. The new service enables me to separate the main view from the loading view, that I could reuse in all pages of the application. I also provided the possibility to configure an error template url and error controller, for when the loading failed.

The Angular $injector, $templateRequest and $controller services do most of the work. I just had to connect a directive, that depends on these services, to the right event ($locationChangeSuccess), and to the promise, retrieved (using $q.all) from the resolve object's functions. This connection was done in the route service. The service selects the right template url and comtroller, and passes it on for the directive to handle.

A shortened version (with the getCurrentConfig method left out):

RouteService:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

// provider: 

    angular.module('pikcachu')
        .provider('pikaRouteService', [function () {

        var routeConfigArray;
        var otherwiseRouteConfig;
        //configuration methods
        this.when = function (url, routeConfig){
            routeConfigArray.push({url: url, routeConfig: routeConfig});
            return this; 
        }
        this.otherwise = function(routeConfig){
            otherwiseRouteConfig = routeConfig;
            return this;
        }
        // service factory:
        this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$q', '$injector', '$templateRequest', 
            function ($rootScope, $location, $q, $injector, $templateRequest) {
                function RouteService() {
                    this.setViewDirectiveUpdateFn = function(){ /*...*/ }

                    function init(){
                        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', onLocationChangeSuccess);
                    }

                    function onLocationChangeSuccess(){
                        // get the configuration based on the current url
                        // getCurrentConfig is a long function, because it involves parsing the templateUrl string parameters, so it's left out for brevity
                        var currentConfig = getCurrentConfig($location.url());
                        if(currentConfig.resolve !== undefined){
                            // update view directive to display loading view
                        viewDirectiveUpdateFn(currentConfig.loadingTemplateUrl, currentConfig.loadingController);
                            // resolve
                            var promises = [];
                            var resolveKeys = [];
                            for(var resolveKey in currentConfig.resolve){
                               resolveKeys.push(resolveKey);
                               promises.push($injector.invoke(resolve[resolveKey]));
                            }
                            $q.all(promises).then(resolveSuccess, resolveError);
                            function resolveSucces(resolutionArray){
                               // put resolve results in an object
                               var resolutionObject = {};
                               for(var i = 0; i< promises.length;++i){
                                  resolved[resolveKeys[i]] = resolutionArray[i];
                               }
                                 viewDirectiveUpdateFn(currentConfig.errorTemplateUrl, currentConfig.errorController);
                            }
                            function resolveError(){
                                viewDirectiveUpdateFn(currentConfig.errorTemplateUrl, currentConfig.errorController);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    init();
                }
                return new RouteService();
            }]
    })();
```

View directive

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('pikachu')
        .directive('pikaView', ['$templateRequest', '$compile', '$controller', 'pikaRouteService', function ($templateRequest, $compile, $controller, pikaRouteService) {

            return function (scope, jQdirective, attrs) {
                var viewScope;

                function init() {
                    pikaRouteService.listen(updateView);
                }

                function updateView(templateUrl, controllerName, resolved) {
                    if(viewScope!== undefined){
                        viewScope.$destroy();
                    }
                    viewScope = scope.$new();
                    viewScope.resolved = resolved;
                    var controller = $controller(controllerName, { $scope: viewScope });
                    $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(onTemplateLoaded);
                    function onTemplateLoaded(template, newScope) {
                        jQdirective.empty();
                        var compiledTemplate = $compile(template)(newScope);
                        jQdirective.append(compiledTemplate);
                    }
                }

                init();
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

Comment: can you please correctly format your solution so that it more clear

Comment: What do you mean? What isn't clear? Should I included code snippets?